# I have questined about get tid on Linux System and result of getpid

Tags: linux, posix

pid : 2394 tid : 2399

pid : 2394 tid : 2398

pid : 2394 tid : 2397

pid : 2394 tid : 2395

***this is using getpid() __NR_gettid***

pid :2529 tid : 1811777280

pid :2529 tid : 1820169984

pid :2529 tid : 1828562688

pid :2529 tid : 1836955392

pid :2529 tid : 1845348096

***this is using pthread_self()***

I am using Fedora17.
I was wondering why tid result differ between getpid() and pthread_self()?

which one is right? my prof. said pthread uses posix not linux system.

and in multi thread condition pid is same? am i got right result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gettid` returns *thread ID* and `pthread_self` returns *POSIX thread ID*. Both differs.

This is the default behavior. See the linux man page of `pthread_self()`. These 3 clauses will clarify it.

> Thread  identifiers  should  be considered opaque: **any attempt to use a
>   thread ID other than in pthreads calls is nonportable** and can  lead  to unspecified results.
>
> Thread IDs are only guaranteed to be unique within a process.  A thread
>          ID may be reused after a  terminated  thread  has  been  joined,  or  a
>          detached thread has terminated.
>
> **The  thread  ID returned by pthread_self() is not the same thing as the
>          kernel thread ID returned by a call to gettid(2)**.

Also this from `gettid` man page

> The  thread  ID  returned by this call is not the same thing as a POSIX
>          thread ID (i.e., the opaque value returned by pthread_self(3))